# Unable to install Android KitKat in Android Studio emulator

Tags: android, emulation, android-4.4-kitkat

I am on Android Studio 4.1.3 on MacOS 10.15.6 (Catalina) and I am unable to create an emulator with Android KitKat API 19-20 on it. The older system I can see available is Lollipop API 21-22.

That's really strange because I have downloaded the whole KitKat SDK as you can see from the SDK manager screenshot below:

[image: SDK manager]

But despite that, I can't see over Lollipop available in AVD:

[image: AVD manager]

I have restarted Android Studio several times after each component download, but no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there anything located under the x86 Images tab in the AVD Manager?

Comment: Oh man, I feel so stupid! I didn't even see that tab! I am such a newbie. All good now, I could find KitKat, install it, and I am ready to go. Thanks so much!!